# Is constructor returning object never used wasteful?

Tags: c#, performance, constructor, static

I'm working with a code base that instantiates objects without assigning to a variable, like so:

```
new MyNonStaticClass();
```

Inside the constructor are calls to static classes/methods anyway...

Whilst this is valid, it's the only usage of the constructor and could be converted to a static method or static class.

This is littered through-out the code base, so the the question is:

**Is there a performance benefit to changing these to static classes?**

I'd like to if I had the time, but I need to prioritise the workload.

Comment: Personally I think readability counts :)

Comment: Me too @JonSkeet, though there is a workload, and I need to prioritise :-)

Comment: I don't understand why performance seems to lead your concerns about this. Calling a ctor without assignment will just result in the object being created then disposed at next GC. The only way this is NOT side-effect free is if the constructor modifies some static state.

Comment: I guess the concern is using more memory than required @Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a performance benefit to changing these to static classes?

Yes - you won't be constructing a load of pointless objects which the GC then has to collect. Is that significant in your application? Hard to tell.

More importantly, there's a significant *readability* benefit. Constructing an object has connotations about per object state being important. A void static method call can *only* have side-effects in terms of exceptions and global state, so it becomes a lot clearer what the purpose of the call is. Plus, you can give it a meaningful name.

I'd expect it to be pretty easy to refactor this with search and replace. (I don't know of tools to do this sort or refactoring easily, given that it's a weird situation. They may exist, but search and replace is probably quicker than finding them.)

Comment: Personally I'd like to clean it up, like I said in my question. I prefer readability. Can I ask what happens to the unused object created by the constructor? Does it go out of scope as if it were assigned and unused?

Comment: @SimonBosley: Objects don't have scope - variables do. But basically there will be no references to it, so it will immediately be eligible for garbage collection. As I said in my answer, I really don't think it would take very long to refector this... particularly if there are many callers but only relatively few classes constructed in this way.

Comment: It's a task that I can add to the project, but it has to be prioritised as part of a large software development team. There's a lot of this kind of code I'm trying to clean-up unfortunately, not just the example I've shown. Personally I wouldn't write this code in the first place ;-)

Comment: new Thing() (if Thing is a class) creates an allocation on the heap (which minimally contains 16 bytes of header, plus whatever state Thing holds) but there will be no reference to that allocation on the stack. GC will come along, suspend all your threads and find all unreferenced allocations, and your new Thing() will be an immediate candidate, so will be reclaimed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your answer, it's good to know about the performance aspect of the situation. Will mark as the answer in due course :-)

Comment: Thanks for adding more information on heap allocation @Matt